# For what values of $a$ and $b$ does the following system of linear equations have infinitely many solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

\begin{align}
x+ay=0 \\
y+bz=0 \\
x+z=0 \\
\end{align}
I have to use row reduction to echelon form in order to solve this. Also, when I tried I didn't find any solutions, so any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $z = -x = ay \to y + b(ay) = 0 \to y(1+ab) = 0$. Thus if $ab = -1$, the system will have infinitely many solutions. Observe that either $a = 0$ or $b = 0$, the system has unique solution $(x,y,z) = (0,0,0)$ as easily checked. I think this method is faster than the row echolon method.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed that! But my teacher wants us to practice with row reduction to echelon form, because that's what is going to be on our midterm. That's why I asked it be done that way.